# Return NULL value if no record found using joins

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Below SQL query for return NULL value if there is no record returns using joins.

My query:

```
SELECT 
    ISNULL((SELECT SR_No
            FROM Product
            WHERE SR_No in ('8877','9911')), NULL)
```

Basically I need to check if the `SR_No` is available in the `Product` table.

How I can modify my script to get output like below:

**Table -> Item_M:**

```
+-------+---------+
| SR_No | Asso_Id |
+-------+---------+
|  4455 |     100 |
|  4455 |     200 |
|  4455 |     300 |
|  8877 |     500 |
|  9911 |     600 |
+-------+---------+
```

**Table->Product:**

```
| SR_No | Pro_N | Pro_Sc |
+-------+-------+--------+
|  4455 | SA    | S      |
|  8877 | BT    | B      |
|       |
+-------+-------+--------+
```

Expected output:

```
+-------+-------+--------+
| SR_No | Pro_N | Pro_Sc |
+-------+-------+--------+
| 8877  | BT    | B      |
| NULL  | NULL  | NULL   |
+-------+-------+--------+
```

Comment: I don't understand the logic behind the result. Why should there be a row of nulls? Where is the join?

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen : how can i use join here , Basically i need to check the "SR_No" available in Product Table

Comment: I still don't get it - both 8877 and 9911 have rows in the Product and `Item_M` table. Also, if you listed 10 products in your `WHERE` and none of them 'qualify', do you expect 10 rows of NULLs or do you at least want to list the `SR_No`
I *think* this is what you are after - http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/51f2c/2

Comment: Yes, I  can add custom text other than NULL if there is no corresponding SR_No in Product table,  But i don't know which logic i have to use here to get it that way... thanks

Comment: Both 8877 and 9911 *are* listed in Product Table. Also, you aren't using Item table at all - is this needed?

Comment: @SamBinHam Please Provide All Table structures

Comment: Sorry , I have modify my product table ..only 4455 & 8877 available i n product table

Comment: @ImranAliKhan i have modify product table,9911 not available in product table , I need to check whether it available in product table or not

Answer (score 2):

This looks like a good fit for using a [Table Valued Constructor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/table-value-constructor-transact-sql) to create a table of the items you are looking for, and then you can `LEFT JOIN` the Products (and possibly Items) table to it, in order to either selectively show the other columns, or NULL if the qualifying criteria aren't met:

```
-- If you want the SR_No number listed along with NULLs
SELECT x.SR_No, p.Pro_N, p.Pro_Sc
FROM (values (8877),(1234)) as x(SR_No)
LEFT OUTER JOIN Product p
on x.SR_No = p.SR_No;
```

Output:

```
SR_No   Pro_N   Pro_Sc
8877    BT      B
1234    (null)  (null)
```

And if you don't want to show the SR_No value alongside the nulls:

```
-- If you want the SR_No listed as NULL instead
SELECT p.SR_No, p.Pro_N, p.Pro_Sc
FROM (values (8877),(1234)) as x(SR_No)
LEFT OUTER JOIN Product p
on x.SR_No = p.SR_No;
```

Giving:

```
SR_No   Pro_N   Pro_Sc
8877    BT      B
(null)  (null)  (null)
```

The problem with the second approach is that you'll be showing multiple rows of `NULL` columns if there are multiple non-matches, which is unlikely to be useful to your code consuming this query.

If you need to further qualify that there must be Item rows present for the product as well then adjust the query:

```
LEFT OUTER JOIN Product p
on x.SR_No = p.SR_No AND EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM Item_M i WHERE i.SR_No = p.SR_No);
```

[SqlFiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/51f2c/2)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN SR_No IN ('8877','9911') THEN SR_No END AS SR_No,
       CASE WHEN SR_No IN ('8877','9911') THEN Pro_N END AS Pro_N,
       CASE WHEN SR_No IN ('8877','9911') THEN Pro_Sc END AS Pro_Sc
FROM Product
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d625c/1)

You can modify it entering subquery in place of `('8877','9911')`.